# Make new collection with removed redundancies

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I just want to copy a collection, but remove redundant entries. One way I can do this of course is by exporting the whole collection, and changing one of the fields to _id. Additionally I could copy the collection and index the field to remove redundancies, but there are way too many.

However, is there a more elegant solution? Perhaps I can do something like this.

```
db.coll.distinct('Query Sequence').forEach(
         function(x){
            db.newcollection.insert(db.coll.findOne({'Query Sequence':x}))})
```

Of course this doesn't work...but does anyone have any solutions to something like this?

Edit - The reason it doesn't work is because the distinct array is also to big.

Edit 2 - Here is what it looks like.

db.coll.find({'Query Sequence': 'ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTGCAGGAGACCTTCACTGAGGCCGAAGAG'})

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5424b996ce5254437868c1c9"),
    "Sequence Id" : "M02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_2557_16557_7",
    "Query Sequence" : "ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTGCAGGAGACCTTCACTGAGGCCGAAGAG",
    "Chain type" : "VH",
    "Format Type" : "imgt",
    "Species" : "human",
    "Top V Hit" : "IGHV1-2*01",
    "Top D Hit" : "N/A",
    "Top J Hit" : "IGHJ4*01",
    "Productive" : "Yes",
    "Productive CDR3" : "True",
    "Strand" : "-",
    "Framework 1 Nucleotides" : "GGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATAT",
    "Framework 2 Nucleotides" : "AAGCCTTGCA",
    "Framework 4 Nucleotides" : "TGCAG",
    "CDR1 Nucleotides" : "AGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAG",
    "CDR3 Nucleotides" : "CGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTG",
    "Framework 1 AA" : "GWGGCTPQYI",
    "Framework 2 AA" : "KPC",
    "Framework 4 AA" : "C",
    "Framework 1 AA Length" : 10,
    "Framework 2 AA Length" : 3,
    "Framework 4 AA Length" : 1,
    "CDR1 AA" : "SSR*RCIQ",
    "CDR3 AA" : "RLGRMHSPVHIVAGEGVSRSL",
    "CDR1 AA Length" : 8,
    "CDR3 AA Length" : 21,
    "Total V Alignment Matches" : 64,
    "Total V Alignment Mismatches" : 1,
    "Total V Alignment Length" : 65,
    "Total V Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "Total V Alignment Identity" : 98.5,
    "FW1 Alignment From" : 7,
    "FW1 Alignment To" : 37,
    "FW1 Alignment Matches" : 31,
    "FW1 Alignment Mismatches" : 0,
    "FW1 Alignment Length" : 31,
    "FW1 Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "FW1 Alignment Identity" : 100,
    "FW2 Alignment From" : 62,
    "FW2 Alignment To" : 71,
    "FW2 Alignment Matches" : 9,
    "FW2 Alignment Mismatches" : 1,
    "FW2 Alignment Length" : 10,
    "FW2 Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "FW2 Alignment Identity" : 90,
    "CDR1 Alignment From" : 38,
    "CDR1 Alignment To" : 61,
    "CDR1 Alignment Matches" : 24,
    "CDR1 Alignment Mismatches" : 0,
    "CDR1 Alignment Length" : 24,
    "CDR1 Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "CDR1 Alignment Identity" : 100,
    "Junction V-End" : "CTGGG",
    "V-D Junction" : "N/A",
    "Junction D-Gene" : "N/A",
    "D-J Junction" : "N/A",
    "Junction J-Start" : "G",
    "Junction Merged" : "CTGGGG",
    "Stop Codon" : "No",
    "V-J frame" : "In-frame",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5424b996ce52544378867c128"),
    "Sequence Id" : "M02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_35567_85D",
    "Query Sequence" : "ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTGCAGGAGACCTTCACTGAGGCCGAAGAG",
    "Chain type" : "VH",
    "Format Type" : "imgt",
    "Species" : "human",
    "Top V Hit" : "IGHV1-2*01",
    "Top D Hit" : "N/A",
    "Top J Hit" : "IGHJ4*01",
    "Productive" : "Yes",
    "Productive CDR3" : "True",
    "Strand" : "-",
    "Framework 1 Nucleotides" : "GGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATAT",
    "Framework 2 Nucleotides" : "AAGCCTTGCA",
    "Framework 4 Nucleotides" : "TGCAG",
    "CDR1 Nucleotides" : "AGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAG",
    "CDR3 Nucleotides" : "CGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTG",
    "Framework 1 AA" : "GWGGCTPQYI",
    "Framework 2 AA" : "KPC",
    "Framework 4 AA" : "C",
    "Framework 1 AA Length" : 10,
    "Framework 2 AA Length" : 3,
    "Framework 4 AA Length" : 1,
    "CDR1 AA" : "SSR*RCIQ",
    "CDR3 AA" : "RLGRMHSPVHIVAGEGVSRSL",
    "CDR1 AA Length" : 8,
    "CDR3 AA Length" : 21,
    "Total V Alignment Matches" : 64,
    "Total V Alignment Mismatches" : 1,
    "Total V Alignment Length" : 65,
    "Total V Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "Total V Alignment Identity" : 98.5,
    "FW1 Alignment From" : 7,
    "FW1 Alignment To" : 37,
    "FW1 Alignment Matches" : 31,
    "FW1 Alignment Mismatches" : 0,
    "FW1 Alignment Length" : 31,
    "FW1 Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "FW1 Alignment Identity" : 100,
    "FW2 Alignment From" : 62,
    "FW2 Alignment To" : 71,
    "FW2 Alignment Matches" : 9,
    "FW2 Alignment Mismatches" : 1,
    "FW2 Alignment Length" : 10,
    "FW2 Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "FW2 Alignment Identity" : 90,
    "CDR1 Alignment From" : 38,
    "CDR1 Alignment To" : 61,
    "CDR1 Alignment Matches" : 24,
    "CDR1 Alignment Mismatches" : 0,
    "CDR1 Alignment Length" : 24,
    "CDR1 Alignment Gaps" : 0,
    "CDR1 Alignment Identity" : 100,
    "Junction V-End" : "CTGGG",
    "V-D Junction" : "N/A",
    "Junction D-Gene" : "N/A",
    "D-J Junction" : "N/A",
    "Junction J-Start" : "G",
    "Junction Merged" : "CTGGGG",
    "Stop Codon" : "No",
    "V-J frame" : "In-frame",
}
```

As you can see, everything is the same except for the ObjectId and Sequence Id. I would just like one document in the new collection. I'm using Mongo 2.6.4

Comment: There are a couple of different ways to answer this. But mostly, "What is a **real** case of a 'redundancy' to you?". You could make that clearer by showing some sample data and an expected result. Approaches will also vary depending on your MongoDB version.

Comment: Why the downvote? Have the decency to explain why

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try the aggregation framework.
The following mongo shell program shows how to do this,
with some additional simplified example docs for a more complete illustration.
Please note the first character change in some docs for "Sequence Id".

The pipeline stages are:

1. $sort descending to order higher "Sequence Id" first
2. $group by "Query Sequence" and accumulate first doc (with higher "Sequence Id") in each group
3. $project fields back to top level
4. $out to save to a new collection

This assumes that your documents all have the same fields.
For anything less regular,
you will have to round-trip the data through a client program -
eliminate the $project and $out in the pipeline,
batch process in your client program,
and manually project the `doc` field to the top level.

You will need the additional disk space to do this.
Allow at least 2x,
1x for the temp space while running the aggregation framework,
and 1x for the new collection result.

For the documention, please see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Hope that this helps.

aggregate-group-first-last.js:

```
var docs = [
    {"Sequence Id":"M02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_2557_16557_7","Query Sequence":"ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTGCAGGAGACCTTCACTGAGGCCGAAGAG","ChainType":"VH"},
    {"Sequence Id":"M02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_35567_85D","Query Sequence":"ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTGCAGGAGACCTTCACTGAGGCCGAAGAG","ChainType":"VH"},
    {"Sequence Id":"B02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_2557_16557_7","Query Sequence":"ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAG","ChainType":"VH"},
    {"Sequence Id":"A02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_35567_85D","Query Sequence":"ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAG","ChainType":"VH"},
    {"Sequence Id":"C02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_35567_85D","Query Sequence":"ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGAT","ChainType":"VH"}
];
db.test.remove({});
db.test.save(docs);
var result = db.test.find().toArray();
var keys = Object.keys(result[0]);
var project = {};
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    project[keys[i]] = "$doc." + keys[i];
}
printjson(project);
function pipelineWithOut(out) {
    pipeline = [
        {"$sort": {"Sequence Id": -1}},
        {"$group": {_id: "$Query Sequence", doc: {"$first": "$$ROOT"}}},
        {"$project": project},
        {"$out": out}
    ];
    printjson(pipeline);
    return pipeline;
}
db.testFirst.drop();
db.test.aggregate(pipelineWithOut("testFirst"), {allowDiskUse: true});
printjson(db.testFirst.find().toArray());
```

$ mongo aggregate-group-first-last.js

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
{
    "_id" : "$doc._id",
    "Sequence Id" : "$doc.Sequence Id",
    "Query Sequence" : "$doc.Query Sequence",
    "ChainType" : "$doc.ChainType"
}
[
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "Sequence Id" : -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$Query Sequence",
            "doc" : {
                "$first" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : "$doc._id",
            "Sequence Id" : "$doc.Sequence Id",
            "Query Sequence" : "$doc.Query Sequence",
            "ChainType" : "$doc.ChainType"
        }
    },
    {
        "$out" : "testFirst"
    }
]
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54299b557d7122b60724e5f5"),
        "Sequence Id" : "B02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_2557_16557_7",
        "Query Sequence" : "ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAG",
        "ChainType" : "VH"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54299b557d7122b60724e5f7"),
        "Sequence Id" : "C02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_35567_85D",
        "Query Sequence" : "ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGAT",
        "ChainType" : "VH"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54299b557d7122b60724e5f4"),
        "Sequence Id" : "M02331_41_000000000_AAW8D_1_1108_35567_85D",
        "Query Sequence" : "ATCTACGGTTGGGGCGGATGCACTCCCCAGTACATATAGTAGCCGGTGAAGGTGTATCCAGAAGCCTTGCAGGAGACCTTCACTGAGGCCGAAGAG",
        "ChainType" : "VH"
    }
]
```